# Error when opening excel file from outlook: by multiple user. Automation

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro in Outlook 2010. It checks if a file is opened by another user, if not then open it, fill it up with data, save it and close it.

When the users use it at the same time, the faster pc seems to win, and the other user is locked out, thus resulting in a error and even freezes Outlook.

First I tried unprotected workbooks, so everyone can use the macros at the same time (I didn't do the isworkbookopen function then), but it resulted in an automation error:

*Run-time error '-2147418111 (80010001)':*

*Automation error*

*Call was rejected by callee* when debugged, it highlighted the wb.open strpath part

Here is a part of my code now:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliSeconds As Long)

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
End Function


Public Sub test()
Sleep 1000
End Sub


Sub Sample()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim xlApp2 As Object
Dim xlWB2 As Object
Dim xlSheet2 As Excel.Worksheet

Const strpath As String = "P:\Head\....xls"
Const strpath2 As String = "P:\Head\....xls"
Dim Ret
Dim Ret2

Z = 0

0:
Ret = IsWorkBookOpen(strpath) 'the path of the workbook
Ret2 = IsWorkBookOpen(strpath2)

If Ret = False Then
GoTo masodikif
Else
GoTo elseag
masodikif:
    If Ret2 = False Then
    GoTo ifvege
    Else
    GoTo elseag

elseag:     Call test
         Z = Z + 1
        If Z = 50 Then
        MsgBox "Please try again in a few second!"            
        End
        Exit Sub
        End If
        GoTo 0:

        End If
        End If

ifvege:


If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.workbooks.Open(strpath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.sheets("Munka1")



If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp2 = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
    Set xlApp2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB2 = xlApp2.workbooks.Open(strpath2)
Set xlSheet2 = xlWB2.sheets("Munka1")
```

A lot of code again

```
xlWB2.Save
xlWB2.Close savechanges:=True

xlWB.Save
xlWB.Close savechanges:=True


Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing

Set xlApp2 = Nothing
Set xlWB2 = Nothing
Set xlSheet2 = Nothing
```

Comment: I think your problem might be with the method you're using to check to see if the workbook is open.  Any user can open a workbook from a network drive in excel at any time.  The only issue is whether or not that user has read/write permission at the same time.  I'd try checking that by using `xlWB.readOnly`.  If another user has read/write to the workbook at the time it is oppened, this will return `True`, if not, it will return `False`.  I'd simplify your code to use this method to check.  I'll post an answer of how I would do the same type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think using the vba primitives to check to see if the workbook is open is the wrong approach here.  I can respect that you're trying to write reusable subs as well, but in this case I think they needlessly complicate your code.  If I were doing something like this, here is how I would approach it.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliSeconds As Long)

Public Sub Sample()
    'I avoid using late binding.  If this is VBS, you'll have to, but if it is in Outlook, I'd set the references.
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB as Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    '... follow the example for the rest of the dims
    Const strpath as string = "P:\Head\....xls"
    Const strpath as string = "P:\Head\....xls"
    Dim Z as integer
    Z = 0
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
    Do until Z = 50 or xlWB.ReadOnly = False
        xlWB.Close
        Set xlWB = Nothing
        Sleep(1000)
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
        Z = Z + 1
    Loop
    If Z = 50 and xlWB.ReadOnly = True then
        MsgBox "Please try again in a few seconds!"
        End
    End If
    'If we've made it here, we have read write access to the workbook
    'Do stuff...
```

I didn't write out all the code to check both workbooks, but you should get the general idea of how to handle it from here.  Not that your approach is wrong outside of using the vba primitives to check to see if the workbook is open, but I think this would be much cleaner and easier to troubleshoot.  I'd recommend you try adapting your code to follow this example.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your way, but it still doesn't work. When both user hit the macro button in the same time, or after 1 sec, one of them's outlook freezes and doesnt't respond, and the others works fine. I have reduced sleep time to 100 and z to 10, so it should have given the program enough time to go through the loop. I have tested it, and it works well, if the workbooks are allready open on my computer.

Comment: Using sleep can be tricky sometimes... Try putting a `doEvents` line after the sleep line.  Sometimes sleeping in a loop like that causes issues.

Comment: Well, the outlook still freezes if they do it in the sametime even though i've put a 
    xlapp.wait now + timevalue("00:00:02") after the 
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath) line

Comment: You should try stepping through it on both computers at the same time.  Use F8 to step through the code and have both users hit the open line at the same time.  You need to identify which line is causing Outlook to lock, and right now I'm not sure I can tell you without looking at it first hand.  I can tell you that I've used this same approach where I work and it has been successful, so I know it can work I just can't tell you why it isn't working for you.

Comment: I will try it, when I can test with them monday, ty for the tip.